# Protractor: selectively disable the promise manager

Tags: protractor

Protractor config provides an option to disable promise manager, however, the setting is applied to all the tests/test suite.

In Protractor, is there a way to disable promise manager in the individual test?

WebDriverJs has something like, [https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs] 
In order to migrate tests bit-by-bit, you can selectively disable the promise manager in before/after blocks:

```
promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;

function legacySuite(name, fn) {
  describe(name, function() {
    before(() => promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = true);
    after(() => promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false);

    fn();
  });
}

describe('Example', function() {
  legacySuite('legacy tests', function() {
    test.it('test 1', function() {
      // ...
    });
  });

  it('test 2', async function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do such thing, because such parameter should be in config of `protractor` instead of inside some runner (Jasmine, Mocha etc.).